# Magento 2 cannot delete module bceause ClassReader.php class not found

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.3.3
I have the module Swissup/Core installed. I had some problems and removed it. After I removed the module, (deleted from composer directory) I can no longer use Magento 2. I get the following when trying to run any commands.

Updating modules:
Class Swissup\Core\Console\Command\ModuleCommand does not exist

In ClassReader.php line 19:

Class Swissup\Core\Console\Command\ModuleCommand does not exist

I checked and there is no attribute created by this module. I checked source_model, frontend_model, backend_model.

I removed all references to the module in composer.json, composer.lock.
I removed all references to it in composer files in vendor directory.
I removed cache, pub/static, generated, and var/cache.
I also did a recursive search across the entire site for any file containing the word swissup or Swissup. None were found.
I also removed the module from the setup table.
I also checked/removed any reference in core_config_data

Still, I cannot use the system and this error persists.
I cleared all composer cache

I also as a test, put invalid credentials in app/etc/env.php to see if the database would cause an issue, but it didn't, I still get this error.

I don't understand, how, if i'm sure by doing a grep in every file a part of Magento and no such reference exists, that this error is raised. There must be some file stored outside of the Magento filesystem. It cannot be a database issue, because the database cannot connect due to me inputting invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you delete Modules by first running `bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Namespace` followed by `composer remove vendor/package` instead of deleting it in the file system.

Do you have a git repository on which you can reset? Does `composer install` generate any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there is the module entry in the `setup_module` table.

If the module you want to delete is `Vendor_Module`, then search for the module in `setup_module` table:

```
SELECT * FROM setup_module WHERE module = "Vendor_Module";
```

If you find the module in `setup_module` table, then you need to remove that from the table:

```
DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module = "Vendor_Module";
```